# Strange/Buggy Characters in the Terminal

Tags: debian, terminal, fonts, character-encoding, special-characters

I use *Debian SID* and the **Terminator** is my terminal emulator. After updating the system the last time (yesterday 2023/11/22) and rebooting, some characters in my terminal in certain commands are showing strange characters.

However, in the same terminal, connected via SSH to Arch Linux, the same commands run without the problem:

[image: example image]

EDIT 1:

I recorded my screen showing the entire problem process and it is at this [LINK](https://imgur.com/htELY7S) (maximize the video for better viewing). Anyway, I'll describe it step by step:

1. *With `terminator` open...*
2. **Split** horizontally (terminator)
3. **Back** to the panel above (terminator)
4. **Split** vertically (terminator)
5. **Go back** to the panel on the left (terminator)
6. Print the variable `$TERM`: `xterm-256color`
7. I run `htop`: it has strange characters
8. **Go** to the panel on the right (terminator)
9. Print the variable `$TERM`: `xterm-256color`
10. I run `ranger`: it has strange characters
11. **Go** to the panel below (where I will make the SSH connection) (terminator)
12. Print the variable `$TERM`: `xterm-256color`
13. I connect to the remote host (Arch Linux which is on the local network) via SSH
14. Print the variable `$TERM`: `xterm-256color`
15. I run `htop`: **NOT** has strange characters
16. Close `htop`
17. I run `ranger`: **NOT** has strange characters
18. Close the `ranger`
19. **I join** a `tmux` session
20. Print the variable `$TERM`: `tmux-256color`
21. **Split** vertically (tmux)
22. **Go back** to the left panel (tmux)
23. I run `htop`: **NOT** has strange characters
24. **Go** to the panel on the right (tmux)
25. Print the variable `$TERM`: `tmux-256color`
26. I run `ranger`: **NOT** has strange characters

Can anyone help?

Comment: Apparently in tmux this can arrive frequently, have you tried https://superuser.com/questions/1336947/weird-characters-appearing-in-the-console to reset characters ? Also, is it still failing if you reboot?

Comment: Please also edit the question and emphasize that you're using `tmux` (the bottom green row gives it away, but I really thought you were using `Terminator`'s split layout, I only noticed `tmux` because of the previous comment). Also emphasize the terminal emulator you're using (currently it's mentioned only once, in all lowercase, with no formatting whatsoever). Please also add these two keywords as tags if such tags are available.

Comment: What's your `$TERM` outside `tmux` (i.e. before starting it up)? What's your `$TERM` inside `tmux`, in each pane (before / after ssh'ing)? Does the issue occur without `tmux`? Please try a couple of other terminals, let's say `xterm`, `konsole`, other non-VTE-based ones you might find; both with and without `tmux`, how do they behave?

Comment: @egmont I'm actually using Terminator, this is the terminal emulator. Tmux is only being used in the lower split (all horizontal part from the middle down) within the SSH connection. I will make all these details clearer in the description.

Comment: I _suspect_ (but this is a blind suspicion) that the bug was triggered by an update to ncurses (probably the `libncurses6` or `ncurses-term` package). Is there a chance you could downgrade to the previous versions of these packages (or rather: second previous, there were two consecutive updates)? If this theory is confirmed then the next question is whether it's a bug in those packages, or a bug in VTE (Terminator).

Comment: Also, please update your system again, _maybe_ the quick followup update of these packages fix this bug and you haven't received that update yet. There was version `6.4+20231118-1` and quickly afterwards version `6.4+20231121-1` released.

Comment: In fact, the commit log of the latest version, pointing to https://bugs.debian.org/cgi-bin/bugreport.cgi?bug=1056340, mentions pretty much the same bug as this. It literally says "htop shows a lot of ^@ characters". So I'm pretty certain it was a faulty ncurses/terminfo package from Debian that is already fixed. Just update your system again :)

Comment: PLEASE, [don't post pictures of text](https://unix.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/4086/psa-please-dont-post-images-of-text)

Comment: @JimL. I firmly disagree. The separators between the four terminals, colors, the replacement glyph box and the CJKs in the top right red area were all important clues for me to locate where the problem likely resides. I would have had a much harder time with text showing `^@` etc., no colors, no replacement glyph in box (or however that would have copy-pasted), presumably the grid layout falling apart there or at CJKs. The post mentions exceptions to the rule, and I firm believe this questions falls in that category. It's not the exact characters that mattered here but the overall feeling.

Comment: Guys, as @egmont well assessed, the bug was indeed fixed, I updated the system and everything is normal now. I confess that I didn't think a fix would come out so quickly and that's why I ended up not even thinking about updating the system again.